How to determine the degrees of freedom and construct the basis functions for natural quadratic spline or other ones except for natural cubic spline?
From  the Chapter 5 of ESL (The Elements of Statistical Learning), we know a degree-$d$  spline or an order-$M$ spline  ($M=d+1$) with $K$ knots $\xi_i, i=1,2,...,K$ has $K+d+1$  degrees of freedom, namely it can be represented by the linear combination of the spline basis:
$$
f(X)=\beta_0+\beta_1b_1(X)+\beta_2b_2(X)+...+\beta_{d}b_d(X)+\beta_{d+1}b_{d+1}(X)+...+\beta_{d+K}b_{d+K}(X)\tag{1}
$$
where,  $b_{j}(X)=X^j$, $j=1,...,d$ ,  $b_{d+i}(X)=(X-\xi_i)_{+}^d$, $i=1,...K$.
For example, a cubic spline with $K$ knots  has $K+4$  degrees of freedom and can be modelled as
$$
f(X) = \sum_{j=0}^3 \beta_j X^j + \sum_{k=1}^K \theta_k (X - \xi_k)_{+}^{3},\tag{2}
$$
where $\theta_k=\beta_{d+k}$.
From ESL,  we also know a natural cubic spline adds additional constraints, namely that the function is linear beyond the boundary knots, which frees up four degrees of freedom (two constraints each in both boundary regions).  From also Ex. 5.4 therein, we further know  a natural cubic spline with $K$ knots has $K$  degrees of freedom and can be represented by $K$ basis functions:
$$
N_1(X)=1,N_2(X)=X,N_{k+2}(X)=d_k(X)-d_{K-1}(X),\quad k=1,2,...,K-2,
$$
where $d_k(X)=\frac{(X-\xi_k)_{+}^3-(X-\xi_K)^3_{+}}{\xi_K-\xi_k}$ .
I wonder if there are natural quadratic spline basis functions. If so, how many degrees of freedom do natural quadratic splines have, and how can they be derived? Or generally how about a natural degree-$d$   spline with $d\ge 2$?  By the way, I'm curious, why is there relatively less information available online about other types of natural splines (natural degree-$d$   spline) compared to natural cubic splines in statistical machine learning field (e.g., splines::bs() in R works for degree-$d$  splines  while splines::ns() only works  for natural cubic spline)?
I made the following attempt.
For a quadratic ($d=2$) spline with $K$ knots $\xi_i, i=1,2,...,K$ , it has $K+3$  degrees of freedom. According to  (1) and (2) it follows
$$
f(X) = \sum_{j=0}^2 \beta_j X^j + \sum_{k=1}^K \theta_k (X - \xi_k)_{+}^{2},\tag{3}
$$
Similar with the natural cubic spline,  a natural quadratic spline is linear beyond the boundary knots, which frees up two degrees of freedom (one constraint each in both boundary regions; i.e., requiring the second derivative to be zero at the boundary regions). Thus, I guess the degrees of freedom of natural quadratic spline with $K$ knots is $K+3-2=K+1$.
Following the natural cubic spline, I further guess a quadratic cubic spline with $K$ knots can be represented by $K+1$ basis functions:
$$
N_1(X)=1,N_2(X)=X,N_{k+2}(X)=d_k(X)-d_{K-1}(X),\quad k=1,2,...,K-1,
$$
where $d_k(X)=\frac{(X-\xi_k)_{+}^2-(X-\xi_K)^2_{+}}{\xi_K-\xi_k}$ .
I am unable to confirm my guesses and would appreciate some suggestions and assistance (or hints).
